Issue with Offer Code Redemption: SKPaymentQueue Observer Not Notified in StoreKit
I'm developing an iOS app that supports in-app purchases and I'm using StoreKit2 for handling transactions. While purchase, promotion, and restore purchase functionalities are working fine, I'm facing an issue with offer code redemption.
When I present the offer code redemption sheet using:
SKPaymentQueue.default().presentCodeRedemptionSheet()

the sheet appears and shows redemption as successful. However, my SKPaymentTransactionObserver does not seem to receive any updates or notifications. Specifically, the paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:) method is not being called.
Here’s a snippet of my SKPaymentTransactionObserver setup:
import StoreKit

class YourClass: NSObject, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    }

    deinit {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
    }

    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                print("Transaction Purchased")
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .failed:
                print("Transaction Failed")
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .restored:
                print("Transaction Restored")
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .deferred:
                print("Transaction Deferred")
            case .purchasing:
                print("Transaction Purchasing")
            @unknown default:
                print("Unknown Transaction State")
            }
        }
    }
}


Steps I’ve Taken:

Verified that the observer is added to the SKPaymentQueue in the initializer and removed in deinit.
Tested on a real device, not just the simulator.
Checked that the offer code is valid and properly set up in App Store Connect.
Verified that the latest version of Xcode is being used.

Questions:

Is there a known issue with offer code redemption in StoreKit2 that might cause the observer not to receive notifications?
Are there additional steps or configurations required to ensure that the transaction observer is notified about offer code redemptions?
Are there any common pitfalls or troubleshooting tips for dealing with this issue?

Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated!

If you are using StoreKit2, you need to use the appropriate StoreKit2 function.
If you are using UIKit then you should use presentOfferCodeRedeemSheet(in:) or if you are using SwiftUI then you should use offerCodeRedemption(isPresented:onCompletion:).
You can then remove all references to SKPaymentQueue and SKPaymentTransactionObserver.

Thanks Paulw11 for your response, my app is supporting iOS 15 and methods you suggested supported from iOS 16. So I need to use StoreKit for offer code. And I also tried methods you suggested I am not getting update in that as well.
I am using StoreKit file for testing the offer code.

The original StoreKit methods are deprecated as of ios 18, so you may want to consider when you are going to drop support for ios15 see the sidebar. However, if you want to use the original StoreKit methods, you need to,provide more information on how you create the YourClass instance. It needs to be created in didFinishLaunching and remain in memory for the lifetime of your app. It should never be deinitialised

I am creating object of manager class in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
_ = SubscriptionManager.shared
public class SubscriptionManager: NSObject, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
public static let shared = AloSubscriptionManager()
}
I am able to see success transaction in Xcode subscription list. But it's now calling update transaction. that I can use for update the UI or server.
How can I get success or failure in app?

Hi @PushpendraSingh i am facing the same problem . did you find any solution ?
